# How do I connect the huge solar panel on the crashed satellite?

Tags: astroneer

I quite often come across a wrecked/crashed satellite with a huge solar panel. If you dig down a bit you can see that it is generating power when the sun is out (the bars flash and fill up). I'd like to connect this to my base. I tried tethering out to it but could not get it to interact with the tethers.

Has anyone managed to connect it, and if so how?

Answer (score 8):

Reading [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Astroneer/comments/5ja32t/how_do_i_hook_up_the_giants_solar_panels_to_my/), it seems that you can't directly connect the solar panel to the base. You need to connect a rover to the solar panel, and then to connect the rover to your base.

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296145/206692) answer does answer the question, the recent Basebuilding Update to the game has changed a few things. The game introduced a new power station based on wires that come out of platforms. So, one way to get connected to the solar panel would be to just place a platform next to it and connect the power. The update also added a new item called extenders which can be used to connect power lines over long distances. See their wiki [page](https://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Extenders).  Just connect the extenders to the solar panel and connect them to a platform at your base.

Answer (score 0):

Once you completely dig out the panel with your excavator tool, you can use a truck with a winch to drag it back to your base.

Once near the base you can connect it.